# Laravel Route Regex Alternative Rule Not Working

Tags: php, regex, laravel, routes, laravel-5

So, im using a regex for handling parameters on my route, but i cant seem to make 2 rules on my `page` var to work together. Here is my code

```
Route::get('/{page}', 'Backend\PageController@viewPage')->where(['type' => 'blog|site', 'page' => '^add$|^[0-9]+$']);
```

Edit: (the route rule is inside a route group, for some who are wondering where the `type` var came from, its from the parent route group)

i want to accept either the string `"add"` or `integers`, but it seems to accept only the first expression (I tried swapping the position of the expression, only the first works).

Any idea whats the problem? since my `type` var also has a regex to accept 2 words. Im runnin on Laravel 5.2 and im just starting on laravel. Thanks

Update

tried

`Route::get('/{page}', 'Backend\PageController@viewPage')->where(['type' => 'blog|site', 'page'=>'^add$|^test$']);`

to make sure that the problem isnt caused by the 2nd expression pattern, still working for the first expression only

Comment: Maybe  `'regex:/^(add|[0-9]+)$/'` will help (same with `'regex:/blog|site/'`).

Comment: `Route::get('/{page}', 'Backend\PageController@viewPage')->where(['type' => 'regex:/blog|site/']);` this doesnt work :( @Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel router (inheriting Symfony router) **[adds](https://github.com/symfony/routing/blob/3.1/RouteCompiler.php#L166)** beginning and end of string anchors (`^`, `$`) accordingly to each where constraint regular expression while removing any **[existing ones](https://github.com/symfony/routing/blob/3.1/Route.php#L568)**. If alternatives are used in a regular epxression `|` then whole pattern is enclosed in parentheses.

So in your case, last compiled RegEx would be something like this:

```
#^/(?:add$|^[0-9]+)$#s
```

FYI first slash `/` is caught from route itself. Now if you take a look at what this RegEx brings you, you will notice that there is a misplaced caret `^` in middle of pattern which denotes to a *beginning* and that never happens.

A solution would be changing your RegEx to this:

```
add|[0-9]+
```

Which will be compiled to:

```
#^/(?:add|[0-9]+)$#s
```

Larave route:

```
Route::get('/{page}', 'Backend\PageController@viewPage')
    ->where(['page' => 'add|[0-9]+']);
```

Comment: Thanks @revo! i tried my regex pattern on regex testers online, and it shows that it works. Never thought that it would be treated differently on laravel